# How do I let my old manager know I don't want to return to his team?

Tags: ethics, internship

I am currently on a years student placement at my company and have spent the last 6 months as an application developer. I have enjoyed this job and learnt a lot of useful skills but I have come to realize that this is not a career path I will want to pursue.

As part of my placement, I have been given the opportunity to work with a variety of different teams within the organisation and spent the first 5 months on a IT service desk.

I've now moved onto a new team and I'm really enjoying it. The problem is that my old manager (application development) is very keen to get me back and working on my old projects. I have mentioned that I would like to spend longer with this team as I only have 3 months left of my placement, but he seems to think that an extra week or so would be sufficient.

I don't want to tread on my old managers toes as the only reason I was able to move to this new team is because of a contact he had within the department. However the idea of going back to staring at code all day makes me feel a little ill.

How should I approach this scenario?

Comment: I would not jeopardize a reference on a week or so or even 3 months.    In the over scheme of things even 3 months is not very long.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply explain that you learned a lot while you were there and feel like coding is not your future. You're an intern, you're young and at a major crossroads in your life and your employer has been there before too. He should understand what it is like, and an intern is not a massive investment for a company to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Speak with the manager of your current team and explain to him/her that you would be thrilled to stay there. Ask her if that is possible and if yes, ask her help to deal with your former manager.